# What's happen when CreateFileAsync write file to a disk which Write access denied or capacity shortage

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I wrote a class which provide the download file function, I use the CreateFileAsync to create file, then use the WriteBytesAsync to write every bytes which downloaded. Does the WriteBytesAsync or CreateFileAsync throw any exception if the destination disk was Write denied or capacity shortage?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If disk is write protected, `UnauthorizedAccessException` could be generate while creating file. I advice you to check if there's free space or not in disk drive. Use below given methods to get the free space & capacity of disk drive.

```csharp
public static class StorageItemExtensions
{
    public static async Task<IDictionary<string, object>> GetSpace(this IStorageItem sf)
    {
        var properties = await sf.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
        return await properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new[] { "System.FreeSpace", "System.Capacity" });
    }

    public static string GetSizeString(this ulong sizeInB, double promoteLimit = 1024, double decimalLimit = 10, string separator = " ")
    {
        if (sizeInB < promoteLimit)
            return string.Format("{0}{1}B", sizeInB, separator);

        var sizeInKB = sizeInB / 1024.0;

        if (sizeInKB < decimalLimit)
            return string.Format("{0:F2}{1}KB", sizeInKB, separator);

        if (sizeInKB < promoteLimit)
            return string.Format("{0:F2}{1}KB", sizeInKB, separator);

        var sizeInMB = sizeInKB / 1024.0;

        if (sizeInMB < decimalLimit)
            return string.Format("{0:F2}{1}MB", sizeInMB, separator);

        if (sizeInMB < promoteLimit)
            return string.Format("{0:F2}{1}MB", sizeInMB, separator);

        var sizeInGB = sizeInMB / 1024.0;

        if (sizeInGB < decimalLimit)
            return string.Format("{0:F2}{1}GB", sizeInGB, separator);

        if (sizeInGB < promoteLimit)
            return string.Format("{0:F2}{1}GB", sizeInGB, separator);

        var sizeInTB = sizeInGB / 1024.0;

        if (sizeInTB < decimalLimit)
            return string.Format("{0:F2}{1}TB", sizeInTB, separator);

        return string.Format("{0:F2}{1}TB", sizeInTB, separator);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```csharp
var filteredProperties = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetSpace();
var diskSpace = ((UInt64)filteredProperties["System.FreeSpace"]).GetSizeString() + " / " + ((UInt64)filteredProperties["System.Capacity"]).GetSizeString();
```